# помогите отсортировать кортеж

Tags: python, кортежи

опишите программу ниже, чтобы она вывела через пробел в одной строке значения самого маленького и самого большого элементов кортежа my_tuple.

```
my_tuple = (-214, 181, -139, 448, -664, -66, 213, 832, 717, -462, -924, -706, -85, -244, -222, -340, -482, -518, -781, 759, -593, 905, -354, -377, -141, -742, 383, -381, 109, -639, -480, -810, -686, 892, -612, 696, 993, 791, 631, -493, -218, -829, -275, 619, -628, -241, -565, -835, -69, 747, 711, -252, -811, -407, -153, 904, 933, -254, 307, -493, -419, -109, -543, 155, -127, 613, -452, -459, 856, 562, 333, -66, -77, -598, -779, -278, 867, 321, -20, -415, -357, 735, -906, -14, -370, 453, -630, -736, -830, -917, 32, 422, -895, 198, 284, 472, -986, -964, -73, 29)
2
my_tuple = list(my_tuple)
3
print(' '.join(map(str,sorted(my_tuple))))
4

​
5
​
6
​
```

Comment: Для получения самого маленького и самого большого значений достаточно просто min и max взять от кортежа, не обязательно сортировать.

Answer (score 1):

ну почти правильно код то написали, отсортировали кортеж
надо же всего лишь выбрать первый элемент (он будет самый маленький) и последний элемент (он будет самый большой) в отсортированном списке

```
my_tuple = sorted(my_tuple)

print(my_tuple[0], my_tuple[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_tuple = (-214, 181, -139, 448, -664, -66, 213, 832, 717, -462, -924, -706, -85, -244, -222, -340, -482, -518, -781, 759, -593, 905, -354, -377, -141, -742, 383, -381, 109, -639, -480, -810, -686, 892, -612, 696, 993, 791, 631, -493, -218, -829, -275, 619, -628, -241, -565, -835, -69, 747, 711, -252, -811, -407, -153, 904, 933, -254, 307, -493, -419, -109, -543, 155, -127, 613, -452, -459, 856, 562, 333, -66, -77, -598, -779, -278, 867, 321, -20, -415, -357, 735, -906, -14, -370, 453, -630, -736, -830, -917, 32, 422, -895, 198, 284, 472, -986, -964, -73, 29)
my_tuple = list(my_tuple)
print(min(my_tuple), max(my_tuple))
```

Comment: Просто не внимательно читал условие)

Comment: Измените вопрос сам вопрос пожалуйста, а этот ответ удалите

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Преобразование в `list` не нужно вообще